# How do you base64 encode marshaled data in Go?

Tags: go

The data is of type `interface{}`, so how do you know what the size of `dst` should be?

```
marshalledJSON, _ := json.Marshal(data)
dst := make([]byte, <length>) // what's <length>?
base64.RawURLEncoding.Encode(dst, marshalledJSON)
fmt.Println("dst:", dst)
```

Comment: If you have binary data, you'll want to encode it *before* calling `json.Marshal`, not after. At this point *you* have it, in whatever type it has. But after, you have `[]byte`, so `len(marshalledJSON)` tells you how long it is. The `base64` package tells you how long the encoded result will be.

Answer (score 4):

Use `EncodedLen`:

```
dst := make([]byte, base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodedLen(len(marshalledJSON)))
```